# d3js v4: How can I apply force to nodes onclick and make it look like a tween?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

Please take a look at [this codepen demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zKkNGB); I'd ask you to click the svg object to see the simulation ticks instantiated and therefore the transition occur. I use a simple function to do so:

```
function transitionTo() {
  simulation
    .on("tick", ticked);
}
```

However, you can see from the demo that the "tween" is nonexistent. To see an example of the tweening I'm suggesting, see [here](https://bl.ocks.org/shimizu/e6209de87cdddde38dadbb746feaf3a3)!

Where have I gone wrong? Does the `ticked()` function know where my nodes are? Do I need to specify my positions to the simulation instead of the nodes?

Key code ( included in above demo link):

```
var data = {
    nodes:d3.range(0, range).map(function(d){ return {label: "l"+d ,r: config.radius,color: d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10)}})      
}
svg
  .attr("width", config.canvas.width)
  .attr("height", config.canvas.height)
  .attr("id", "canvas")
  .style("border", "1px solid black")
  .attr("onclick", "transitionTo()");
}

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
  .force("collide",d3.forceCollide( function(d){return d.r + 1 }).iterations(15) )
  .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(1))
  .force("center", d3.forceCenter(config.canvas.width / 2, config.canvas.height / 2))
  .force("y", d3.forceY(0))
  .force("x", d3.forceX(0));

var node = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "nodes")
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data(data.nodes)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("r", function(d){  return d.r })
  .attr('cx', function(d, i) { return i % 10 * (config.canvas.width - config.margin.x*2) / 10 + config.radius + config.margin.x; })
  .attr('cy', function(d, i) {return (Math.floor(i/10) * (config.canvas.height - config.margin.y*2) / 10) + config.margin.y + config.radius});

var ticked = function() {
  node
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
}  

simulation
  .nodes(data.nodes);

function transitionTo() {
  simulation
    .on("tick", ticked);
}
```

I prefer answers that are for d3 v4, but any ideas would be very much welcome! Thanks from this d3 noob.

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason your not seeing any tween is that the solution is being converged on very quickly - i.e. the first iterations of the "ticked" function calculates x and y very close to the end solution. You can see the dots shimmer a bit at the end of the simulation as they find their final positions.

So yes - ticked does know where the nodes are (via d.x and d.y) and you shouldn't have to specify their positions to the simulation.

To see your nodes animate from the initial position to the end solution, one option would be to tweak your simulation settings to something less efficient.

e.g. I added a velocityDecay and changed the forceCollide iterations to 1.

```
  var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .velocityDecay(0.05)
    .force("collide",d3.forceCollide( function(d){return d.r + 1 }).iterations(1) )
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(1))
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(config.canvas.width / 2, config.canvas.height / 2))
    .force("y", d3.forceY(0))
    .force("x", d3.forceX(0));
```

Here's an [updated codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rrmLzV)

There is probably a cleaner solution using d3.transition().